# How i can use query formula to get values if cell value conatin mention word in data?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I want to get values from one sheet to my other sheet. But want to fetch only values from Column A if value contains 202 value like bellow.

```
Column A     |             
===============
Hello        |          
World! 202   |        
Foo          |            
Bar 2021     |
```

Now I want to get values only which contain 202 like bellow

in sheet 2 I want result like this

```
    Column A     |             
    ===============
    World! 202   |                      
    Bar 2021     |
```

I try this formula but unable to get data

```
=iferror(query(Data!A:A, "where A CONTAINS =202,0),"no submition yet"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data is a string query is going to treat it as a string.

```
=query(A:A, "where A CONTAINS '202'")
```

You were missing the ' ' around the text 202 and also you have a lot of typos.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:A, REGEXMATCH(A:A, "202"))
```

Comment: consider adding more explanation